# Java stream how to unpack a object with quantity to list of single object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of "Item" objects list like:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int qty;

    public Item() { }

    public Item(String name, int qty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public List<Item> unpack() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item("foo", 2));
        items.add(new Item("bar", 3));
        items.add(new Item("baz", 1));

        List<Item> unpackedItems = unpack(items);
        System.out.println(unpackedItems.size()); // it should be == 6
        return unpackedItems;
    }

    private List<Item> unpack(List<Item> items) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Is there a way to "unpack" those object using streams to have a list of items eventually repeated if *qty* is greater than 1 so at the end I'll have objects with *qty* equals to 1?

Comment: It's not clear to me what method `unpack()` should return. Can you [edit] your question and post the list you want the method to return? How many elements would be in that list for the sample list you create in your code? What would be the `name` and `qty` of each element in the list returned by method `unpack()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can flatten a nested stream based on `qty` (this basically creates a `qty`-sized int stream that is then mapped to a new `Item` with `qty = 1` per element, reusing the name):

```
private List<Item> unpack(List<Item> items) {
    return items.stream()
            .flatMap(item -> IntStream.range(0, item.qty)
                               .mapToObj(i -> new Item(item.name, 1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```